# Rock Paper Scissors easy winning system

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'm trying to make rock paper scissors game but I realize I made very bad code and it got a lot of if statement. Is there anyway to make it simple winning system.

```
rock     -> 0
paper    -> 1
scissors -> 2

if(equal) print('Draw')
if(select1==0 && select2==2) print('rock wins')
.
..
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Only other way I can think of is using `switch() {}` statements. You can learn more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). I've shown a simple example below.

```
switch(VARIABLE HOLDING ANSWER) {
    case "rock":
        // Run code (eg. console.log("Player wins!"))
        break;
    case "paper":
        // Same as above
        break;
    case "scissors":
        // Same as above
        break;
}
```

Also, unsure about this, but I don't think `print()` exists in JavaScript, but `window.print()` does; I'm pretty confident `window.print()` doesn't do what you want. `console.log()` does do what I think you want though.

Comment: Yeah print doesn't exist ,I worte it in javascript thanks for your helping